slider not responding in servo
enter image description here
i hope you guys can help me
I haven't found a way out of all this for several hours, I've searched all the way to the root but there's no enlightenment
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("300x200")
var = DoubleVar()
isSweep = False

def servo_handler(angle):
    if not isSweep :
        print(angle)
        servo.write(angle)

def sweep():
    servo_angle = 0
    for angle in range(180):
        servo_angle = angle
        servo.write(servo_angle)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    isSweep = False

button_OK = Button(screen, text="Sweep", command=sweep)
button_OK.pack(anchor=CENTER)
w = Scale(screen, variable=var, orient=HORIZONTAL, from_=0, to_=180)
w.pack(anchor=CENTER)


screen.mainloop()

this is the code bro please help
